# TFS with Sharepoint Services or Server?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

What is the difference between a TFS installation with Sharepoint Services and one with Sharepoint Server? What are the limitations of the former?

Thanks

Comment: Ander, you might post your question on sharepoint.stackexchange.com too. You are more likely to get answers for SharePoint questions there then you are here.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to licensing. If you have a SharePoint server license you would like to use for your TFS web portal, or would you like to install a new instance of SharePoint Services(which is free).